# how to use local files like css from android in order to not to charge it from the web page

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have a doubt about the possible use of this method when trying to load a web page from a server, example: "www.mitiendafavorita.com", through a WebView in Android Studio, this page loads all its CSS and js together, increasing the amount of download.

WHEREBY.

**is there a way to load a web page, but within the code (CSS,js) of that web page, in order just to link addresses of CSS and js, in order to take them from a local fixed folder in the android studio application "assets", in order to do not have to download the files (CSS,JS) each time the web page loads?**

IN ANDROID STUDIO:
if I use this method, I must necessarily have the CSS files, and js in the same folder to work

```
< myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ejemplo.html");>
```

and ejemplo.html should have in its code structure:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extra.css">
```

by this way, everything works great, because the CSS is in the same HTML folder. Both inside the assets folder of the android application

SO.

if I load a page with the Webview, example: www.mitiendafavorita.com, how could I use the CSS and js hosted in the local "assets" folder of the application?

I already tried the put the address in it, but it did not work: :(

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/extra.css">
```

thank you very much to the people that could help me: '(

Comment: `but it did not work` it should work. Probably you did it incorrectly? Also if it does not work, you could try to inject the style directly to the HTML page

Comment: Have you tried webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true)? There are a few setAllowFile* functions in webview, and I'm not sure what they do, you should try them: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html